# CSS animation/keyframes when items are removed from dom in div?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, css-animations, keyframe

I wrote some code that automates the BS4 toasts so I can call them on the fly with options.  When a new toast is added to the container it shows below the previous.  When a toast expires it is removed from the dom.  When that happens the toast fades out (due to BS's .fade .show classes) and when that animation completes the entire toast is removed from the dom.  Everything works as it should, but at this time is also when any other toasts 'bump up/down' in the container since one has been removed.  Is there a way to animate the movement of the existing toasts when another toast is removed from the dom?  So they don't 'jump' into their new spots?

Here is an example of what I am looking at when my container has two toasts :

```
<div id="toasts" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true">
    <div id="toasts-container">

        <div id="App_toast_288951045797" class="toast toast-info fade show" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" data-autohide="false">
            ...content
        </div>

        <div id="App_toast_288951046236" class="toast toast-info fade show" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" data-autohide="false">
            ...content
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Removes from dom after toast is closed :

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.toast', '.toast', function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

For those of you who 'don't understand what I'm asking.

```
<div id="div1">number one</div>
<div id="div2">number two</div>
<div id="div3">number three</div>
```

Put the above in a page.  Remove #div1 from the dom.  What happens?  #div2 and #div3 move up because #div1 no longer exists.  I am wondering if that movement can be animated so it does not happen instantly.

Comment: Unclear what I'm asking - really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't quite have enough (non-pseudo) HTML in it for me to give you a more useful snippet, but the below is a simple example that should get the point across.

The solution is to animate the height of the element.

Basic approach:

1. fade element out
2. once it's faded out, animate/transition its height down to 0px
3. after it's zero pixels tall, remove it from the DOM

Try clicking the first or second item in the list here:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.toast').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass('animate');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $this.remove();
    }, 800);
  });
});
```

```css
.toast {
  height: 30px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 350ms ease, height 350ms ease 400ms;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.toast:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: navy;
}
.toast:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: steelblue;
}
.toast:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: powderblue;
}
.animate {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toasts">
  <div class="toast">lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="toast">dolor sit amet</div>
  <div class="toast">consectetur adipiscing</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, I am getting somewhere with this when using a set height on .toast and have the behavior like I was looking for, but I can't have a set height for it - needs to be dynamic.  Any work around there?

Comment: @user756659 since you can't transition from `auto` to something else with just CSS, your best bet is to get the computed height immediately before you animate it, set that as the height inline, then do the animation. Look into `element.getBoundingClientRect()`. If you have margins between the items, you'll want to account for those as well for the best possible transition. That gets a little more complicated.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  Yes, I already realized I need border-width:0; and margin-bottom:0; as well in my animate class to make sure everything is smooth.